# How can I append a specific derived text to the end of each line in a file?

Tags: linux, shell-script

(the specific text is derived from a field from the file using a case statement)
ex.
input file:

```
MYFILEA|ssss|1111|                                  
MYFILEB|ffff|2222|                       
MYFILEC|ssss|3333|
```

case statement will use the 5th char from each line to determine which case statement to append to each line

```
A-'Apple'
B-'Banana'
C-'Carrot'
```

expected output:

```
MYFILEA|ssss|1111|Apple              
MYFILEB|ffff|2222|Banana           
MYFILEC|ssss|3333|Carrot
```

My current approach is this:

```bash
rm MYOUTPUT.txt
touch MYOUTPUT.txt
filename="MYINPUT.txt"
while read line
do
  ENDTEXT=`echo $line | cut -c7`
  #echo $ENDTEXT
  case $ENDTEXT in
    A)
      APPTEXT="Apple" ;;
    B)
      APPTEXT="Banana" ;;
    C)
      APPTEXT="Carrots" ;;
    *)
      APPTEXT="XXXX" ;;
  esac


  echo $APPTEXT
  sed 's/$/'APPTEXT'/' >> MYOUTPUT.txt
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. So, what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: The 5th char in all your input lines is `L`, isn't it?

Comment: This feels like a homework question. What attempts have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: DonHolgo, thanks it should be 7th char.

Comment: Not homework, actually work, just an example the real work is alittle more complicated, kind of stuck on adding the APPTEXT to the end of the file with the sed command.  It's not working correctly.

Comment: rm MYOUTPUT.txt
touch MYOUTPUT.txt
filename="MYINPUT.txt"
while read line
do

  ENDTEXT=`echo $line | cut -c7`
  #echo $ENDTEXT
  
  case $ENDTEXT in

      A)
         APPTEXT="Apple" ;; 
      B)
         APPTEXT="Banana" ;; 
      C)
         APPTEXT="Carrots" ;; 
     
      *)
         APPTEXT="XXXX" ;;
  esac
   
   
  echo $APPTEXT 
  sed 's/$/'APPTEXT'/' >> MYOUTPUT.txt
  echo $APPTEXT
  echo $line
  
  

done < "$filename"

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash:

Script `add_column.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -u

# get 1st parameter as input filename
declare -r input_filename="$1"
# key
declare k=
# value
declare v=

# read all lines from input file
while read -r line; do
    #echo "l='$line'"

    # get key
    k="${line:6:1}"
    #echo "k='$k'"

    # determine value for each key value
    case "$k" in
        'A')
            v='Apple'
        ;;
        'B')
            v='Banana'
        ;;
        'C')
            v='Carrot'
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown key '$k'"
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    # print result
    echo "$line$v"

done < "$input_filename"
```

with:

```bash
chmod +x add_column.sh
```

Executed like this:

```
add_column.sh input.txt
```

Result:

```
MYFILEA|ssss|1111|Apple
MYFILEB|ffff|2222|Banana
MYFILEC|ssss|3333|Carrot
```